# Passing item through props

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to pass down the object through props to show the user more details about the item on the detail page but something seems to be broken. It gives me a './src/components/Trial.js Line 38:  Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected "," ' error

My brewery.js

```
import React from "react";
import Trial from './'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

class Brewery extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      breweries: []
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch("https://api.openbrewerydb.org/breweries")
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then((data) => {
        this.setState({
          breweries: data,
        })
      })
  }

  renderBreweries = () => {
    const { breweries } = this.state;
    return breweries.slice(0,10).map((brewery) =>
      <Brewery key={brewery.id} brewery={brewery} />
  )
  }

  render() {

    const { breweries } = this.state;

    return(
      <div>
        {this.renderBreweries()}
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default Brewery;
```

My trial.js

```
import React from "react";
import Brewery from "./Brewery";

class Trial extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const { brewery } = this.props;
    return(
      <div>
        {brewery.name}
      </div>

  }
}

export default Trial;
```

Comment: where you are using trial?

Comment: I'm not using it anywhere in brewery.js, it directs to a different path

Comment: Why do you call Brewery into Brewery seems to be infinite issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You have bracket issue in trial.js
2. You are running into infinite calls, creating brew in did mount

   `return breweries.slice(0,10).map((brewery) =>
         <Brewery key={brewery.id} brewery={brewery} />
     )`

Every time this calls you are again calling the api and getting the same data. because of this you are never gonna get the result.

Create new component to render the result or you can use existing one but do not call recursively. something like this

```
export const RenderBreweries=(props) =>{
  return <div>{props.brewery.id}</div>
}
```

And call it like this

```
return breweries.slice(0, 10).map((brewery) =>
      <RenderBreweries key={brewery.id} brewery={brewery} />
    )
```

This will render the breweris. and yes you will get the props passed key and brewery by `props.key` and `props.brewery`

Your component should look like this

```
import React from "react";
import Trial from './'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

class Brewery extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      breweries: []
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {   
    fetch("https://api.openbrewerydb.org/breweries")
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then((data) => {
        this.setState({
          breweries: data,
        })
      })
  }

  renderBreweries = () => {
    const { breweries } = this.state
    return breweries.slice(0, 10).map((brewery) =>
      <RenderBreweries key={brewery.id} brewery={brewery} />
    )
  }

  render() {
   console.log(this.breweries)
    const { breweries } = this.state;

    return (
      <div>
        {this.renderBreweries()}
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export const RenderBreweries=(props) =>{
  return <div>{props.brewery.id}</div>
}

export default Brewery;
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-2h79tb)

Comment: @razvanusc use `<div>{props.brewery.name}</div>` instead of `<div>{props.brewery.id}</div>`

Comment: Alright, and is it possible to make them clickable by adding a link tag?

Comment: @razvanusc yes, I can not give you entire coding instructions, try to understand my answer  and proceed with learning next step. if you have any question you can ask separately. I have explained much details into answer.

Answer (score 0):

You open a parenthesis after return in `Trial.js` and never close it.

```
class Trial extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const { brewery } = this.props;
    return(
      <div>
        {brewery.name}
      </div>
    ); //<-- missing part
  }
}
```

I would recommend using a linter, like `eslint` that can save you from a lot of errors like this.

Comment: That fixed the error but, nothing from the API is returned

Comment: This is a different problem. In you `renderBreweries` you are calling `Brewery` component recursively. I guess, you actually want to call `Trial` there.

Answer (score -1):

You have an extra `,` after `breweries: data` (should not be the case though) , did you try removing that ?

```
componentDidMount() {
fetch("https://api.openbrewerydb.org/breweries")
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then((data) => {
    this.setState({
      breweries: data,
    })
  })
}
```

and below as well, there is a missing parenthesis, you can change `Trial` as below,

```
class Trial extends React.Component {
    render() {
    return(
      <div>
        {this.props.brewery.name}
      </div>
    ); // here
  }
}
```

So when you want to render a Trial, you should use,

```
<Trial brewery={brewery} />
```

Comment: Yea, doesn't change anything